# Perl STDIN syntax

Tags: perl, io

I have run into two different syntax to read input from STDIN that work and I can't figure out if there is a difference between the two.

The first method I was introduced to was:

```
$IN = Bio::SeqIO->new(-fh => *STDIN{IO}, '-format' => 'fasta', '-alphabet' => $moltype);
```

Later on after asking some questions on the BioPerl IRC I was told to write it like this:

```
$IN = Bio::SeqIO->new(-fh => \*STDIN, '-format' => 'fasta', '-alphabet' => $moltype);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*STDIN{IO}` will return a reference to the IO object.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump(*STDIN{IO})'
SV = IV(0x166b988) at 0x166b998
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x1688fe0
  SV = PVIO(0x168b5f0) at 0x1688fe0
    ...
```

`\*STDIN` will return a reference to glob that contains the IO object.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump(\*STDIN)'
SV = IV(0xf5f988) at 0xf5f998
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0xf7cfc8
  SV = PVGV(0xf749b0) at 0xf7cfc8
     ...
```

All Perl builtins can handle both<sup>[1]</sup>, but the latter should be better supported by XS modules<sup>[2]</sup> because it's what `open $fh, ...` places in the scalar.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'open(my $fh, "<", "/dev/null") or die; Dump($fh);'
SV = IV(0x144a518) at 0x144a528
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,ROK)
  RV = 0x142c998
  SV = PVGV(0x1485c80) at 0x142c998
     ...
```

---

1. They can also handle the glob directly (e.g. `*STDIN`) or the symbol name as a string (e.g. `"STDIN"`).
2. Modules written in another language.

Answer (score 1):

For all intents and purposes, they are equivalent. You'll more often see the `\*STDIN` form, whereas I prefer `*STDIN{IO}`.

The form `\*STDIN` creates a reference to a “typeglob”. A glob is an entry in Perl's package symbol table. Each glob contains references of various types – the glob `*foo` has a hash `%foo` which is accessible as `*foo{HASH}`, an array `@foo` at `*foo{ARRAY}`, a scalar, a format, a subroutine, and an IO thingy: `*foo{IO}`. Any slot may be undefined if no corresponding variable exists.

The “IO thingy” will be an object that `->isa('IO::Handle')` on any current Perl. This is a full-blown object with methods etc.. So we can do

```
my $fh = *STDOUT{IO};
$fh->say("foo"); # you may need to "use IO::File" to actually load the methods
```

but as a convenience, `STDOUT->say("foo")` (bareword) and `(\*STDOUT)->say("foo")` (glob reference) work as well, although they are different types.

Comment: They were IO::Handle in 5.8. I think they've been IO::Handle objects since 5.6.

Comment: Also, `perl -le'*STDOUT->print("abc");'` and `perl -le'"STDOUT"->print("abc");'`